# what is the probability to find the a sequence of 5 or more continuous heads in coin tossing 100 times?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, matlab

If an unbiased coin is tossed 100 times, what is the probability to find the a sequence of 5 or more continuous heads in the experiment? My Professor says there is no exact way (may be he meant easy method) to find it. Is that true? And I am confused with counting. I simulated this situation using MATLAB.

```
N=10000;
x=randi([0 1],N,100);
idx1=0;
for i=1:N
    idx = findpattern(x(i,:), [1 1 1 1 1]);
    %http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2008/09/08/finding-patterns-in-arrays/
        if(isempty(idx) )
            idx1=idx1+1;
        end
end
p=1-(idx1/N)
```

p is around $80 \%$

---

EDIT : If there is an exact method to find this probability, then can someone do it?

Comment: I can state that there most certainly is an exact way to find it.  Whether there's an _easy_ exact way to find it is another story.   Proof that there is an exact way to find it:  List all possible sequences of 100 coin flips.    Count the number with 5 or more heads in a row.    Divide :)

Comment: In my opinion, your professor is wrong. There is an exact way to find it, it is just a very long computation, involving many large binomial (i.e., factorial) expressions. Alternatively, you can simply go over each of the $2^{100}$ combinations, and count those with a sequence of $5$ or more continuous heads. It'll take you a long time to complete it, but it is still an exact way.

Comment: may be he meant so....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $a_n$ be the number of $n$-letter binary words with no 5 consecutive zeroes.

Clearly $a_i=2^i$ for $i<5$.

Defining $b_n$ to be the words with no 5 consecutive zeroes and ending in $10000$,
$c_n$ to be the words with no 5 consecutive zeroes and ending in $1000$,
$d_n$ to be the words with no 5 consecutive zeroes and ending in $100$,
$e_n$ to be the words with no 5 consecutive zeroes and ending in $10$ and
$f_n$ to be the words with no 5 consecutive zeroes and ending in $1$,
you get following recurrences:

$a_n=b_n+c_n+d_n+e_n+f_n$

$a_{n+1}=a_n+f_n+e_n+d_n+c_n$

$b_n=c_{n-1}$

$c_n=d_{n-1}$

$d_n=e_{n-1}$

$e_n=f_{n-1}$

$f_n=a_{n-1}$

This reduces to $a_{n+1}=a_n+a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}+a_{n-3}+a_{n-4}$.

Implementing this recurrence is totally trivial and computing $a_n$ for $n=100$ will be done in the blink of an eye.

Now subtract the result from $2^{100}$ and divide by $2^{100}$ and you have your (exact) probability.

A Java implementation finds that the number of 'good words' (at least 5 consecutive zeroes) is 1026935919671913581551557828400 (out of $1267650600228229401496703205376=2^{100}$), which indeed is slightly more than 80%.

Comment: Yes its slightly more than $80 \%$ and thanks for the effort (p was 0.8054 for my calculations.)